# Here API - v7 / v8 transaction allowance

Tags: here-api

I currently use Here API v7 and get a free 250k transaction allowance per month which I use for getting route directions.

I see that v7 is now discontinued and I need to migrate to v8.

Looking at their website, there is no mention of the 250k transactions anymore, just a daily 1k allowance, so presumably this has changed.

Does anyone know if I switch to using v8 whilst keeping my existing account whether I will still have the 250k allowance or will it drop to the new one. It’s quite a big difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you continue to use the existing developer portal account, you will still get a free 250k transaction allowance per month for all location services including Routing V8 API. The daily 1k allowance applies to the account in platform and subscribes to the Limited Plan.